# Using patched library before publishing new version to M2 repository

Tags: maven, github, open-source

This is first time when I want to involve into fixing third-party open-source library. Library is hosted on github, so I made a fork of this lib, I cloned my fork to my computer and created feature branch for this fix (To do single commit merge afterwards) This is not a problem.

The problem is time after I do the fix and before library author publishes fix to maven repository. I would like to use this library in my project as fast as I fix this particular bug. I am currently only one person working on a project (this is my pet project, really). But this is a matter of time until I will get into such trouble with my commercial work where I am not the only guy working on project.

I see four resolutions of this problem:

- Publish it to local maven repo

  - I know how to do it
  - Problematic in CI environment
- Configure local dependency in gradle

  - Ugly
  - Problematic in CI
- Publish to public maven

  - Works in CI
  - Never done it
  - This isn't my library - I don't want do sign under not my work
- Private Maven hosted on my VPS

  - Always wanted to have one
  - Works with CI
  - I will have to spent some time reading - since I've never done it

How would you do it? Is any of my approaches right, or I should take whole different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely option 4: "Private Maven hosted on my VPS".

Setting up a private repository manager is actually not that difficult. There are a couple of open-source repository manager, like [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/), [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi). I personnally have always used Artifactory so I can't speak for the others, but there is a [very good official guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Welcome+to+Artifactory) for Artifactory that explains very well how to set it up and configure it.

Note that using a private repository manager has also a lot of other advantages:

- It serves as a cache for public Maven repositories, thereby avoiding to download every dependency from the Internet. This is especially useful in context where Internet access is restricted.
- It can host private libraries produced by your projects or not, the same way public libraries are hosted. As an example of this that I had to deal with is the Oracle JDBC driver: it is not publicly available and it is a mess to install on every developer machine.
- Using it is transparent for Maven projects: dependencies are declared exactly the same way, whether it is a public artifact or a in-house one.

So, not only is using a repository manager a good idea for your current problem, it might also solve a lot of your future problems.

Plus, as you said, the other options are very fragile, for the exact reasons you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Tunaki for your answer. Also thanks for Showing me artifactory guide. I was looking for various private repositories about year of two ago, and I saw artifactory with really old and ugly interface - which made me drop it from consideration. I'll give it a spin, definitely.